# How to modify a list of filenames in scons?

Tags: scons

I use to use this simple Makefile to compile all `.cc` files in the current directory

```
SRCS:=$(wildcard *.cc)
OBJS:=$(SRCS:.cc=)

CXX := clang++                                                             
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -g

all: $(OBJS)
```

I'm trying to translate this into an `SConstruct` file. I can use scons' `Glob` built-in to get the `.cc` file list but I don't know how to remove their suffix (like the `OBJS := $(SRCS:.cc=)` do). Of course I can write Python code to do the modification but does scons has built-in support for this kind of modification?

UPDATE:

My original `SConstruct` file (literally list all the `.cc` files)

```
env = Environment(CXX="clang++", CXXFLAGS=['-std=c++11', '-g'])

env.Program("1.1.cc")
env.Program("1.2.cc")
env.Program("1.3.cc")
env.Program("1.4.cc")
```

One version that works

```
import glob
env = Environment(CXX="clang++", CXXFLAGS=['-std=c++11', '-g'])

sources = glob.glob("./*.cc")

for s in sources:
    env.Program(s)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need the filenames without extensions? You dont need to do that in SCons. You can just use either the Library() builder or the Program() builder with the cc filenames, and SCons will do the rest. If you show us your SConstruct, it would we easier to help.

Comment: @Brady That's because GNU make has the rule that can automatically compile `example.cc` into `example`. So if I can have a `PHONY` target depending on every `.cc` filename without suffix, I can get each `.cc` compiled. I was trying to accomplish the same task in `scons`

Comment: I answered below. The real benefit of SCons over make (in addition to the Python syntax) is the implicit dependency checking that SCons has. It automatically determines header file and library dependencies without having to explicitly list them, and does so very accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response to my question in the comments above, it appears that you want SCons to automatically create a binary or object file based on the source file.

This can be done in SCons as follows:

```
env = Environment()

# This will build example.o
env.Object('example.cc')

# This will build main
env.Program('main.cc')
```

Here is the output from this build:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o example.o -c example.cc
g++ -o main.o -c main.cc
g++ -o main main.o
scons: done building targets.
```

If you need to build a binary with more than one source file, then you will need to specify the binary name, as follows:

```
Program(target = 'myBinary', source = ['main.cc', 'example.cc'])
```

This will create `main.o` and `example.o`, but cant know the name of the binary/program, so you have to specify it.

As for your example with `glob`, Scons has a built-in `Glob()` function, so you could do the following:

```
env = Environment(CXX="clang++", CXXFLAGS=['-std=c++11', '-g'])

sources = Glob("./*.cc")

for s in sources:
    env.Program(s)
```

The SCons Glob() function is not recursive, so if you need to recursively list files, then you'll need to do it differently.